# TraceSource from referenced library not logging when programmatically added

Tags: c#, tracesource

Here is my config file from my Winforms application. Currently it has MyTraceSource commented out, and if I uncomment it and run my program it works as expected. I get output to my console from my referenced library. MyTraceSource is a Trace source that is instantiated and used in my referenced library that I'll call MyOposServiceObject. You'll notice that I setup another TraceSource in my Logger.cs file called TestApplication. That trace source is my logging that I use in the test application (what a logical name...) Just so that I'm clear there are 2 trace sources instantiated and used in 2 different projects. One is a class library, and the other is a winforms application. If i compile my winforms application as a console program and uncomment my TraceSource in the app.config file I get logging from MyOposServiceObject to the console. Clear as mud??? ok on to some code.

**App.config**

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true"/>
    <sharedListeners>
        <!-- Outputs to a Log File-->
        <add name ="file" type ="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="DEMO.log">
            <filter type="System.Diagnostics.EventTypeFilter" initializeData="Off"/>
        </add>
        <!-- Outputs to the console-->
        <add name="console" type ="System.Diagnostics.ConsoleTraceListener" >
            <filter type="System.Diagnostics.EventTypeFilter" initializeData="All"/>
        </add>
    </sharedListeners>
    <sources>
        <!--<source name="MyTraceSource" switchValue="All" >
            <listeners>
                <remove name="Default"/>
                <add name="console"/>
            </listeners>
        </source>-->
    </sources>
</system.diagnostics>
```

However, I don't want my program to be a console program so I made a custom TraceListener.

**MyTraceListener.cs**

```
public class MyTraceListener : TraceListener
{
    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox output;
    public MyTraceListener(System.Windows.Forms.TextBox output)
    {
        this.Name = "FancyTrace";
        this.output = output;
    }
    public override void Write(string message)
    {
        output.SafeSetText(string.Format("{0}\r\n[{1}] {2}",output.Text, DateTime.Now.ToString("F"), message));
    }

    public override void WriteLine(string message)
    {
        Write(message + Environment.NewLine);
    }
}
```

I wired it up like this

**Logger.cs**

```
    internal static void ShowDebugWindow()
    {
        if (debugWindow != null) return;

        debugWindow = new Form();
        debugWindow.TopMost = true;
        debugWindow.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedToolWindow;
        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        tb.Multiline = true;

        tb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        debugWindow.Controls.Add(tb);
        MyTraceListener myTrace = new MyTraceListener(tb);
        trace.Listeners.Add(myTrace);
        opos.Listeners.Add(myTrace);
        debugWindow.Show();
    }
    private static TraceSource trace = new TraceSource("TestApplication");
    private static TraceSource opos = new TraceSource("MyTraceSource");
```

now `trace` is used in this application, and output from it indeed goes to my little debug window. but i get nothing from opos. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In your app.config, `MyTraceSource` is commented out. That could be it.

Comment: @ZacharyYates  If i uncomment it i still get nothing in my debug window, but I do get output to the console.

Comment: My first guess is that TraceListener needs to have all the overridable methods supplied, TraceEvent, etc, (except TraceInfo, that one only matters if you TraceInfo)

Comment: You might need to specify the `SourceLevels` in your `TraceSource`, try: `new TraceSource("MyTraceSource", SourceLevels.All);`

Comment: @ZacharyYates I tried SourceLevels.All and no change.

Comment: @MatthewMartin I gave it a go and implemented all the Write and Trace methods, and still no dice.

Answer (score 0):

To summarize, you want all of your `TraceSource`s from both projects to show up in both your little debug window, the console, and any shared listeners, correct?

I'm assuming your app structure is like:

```
- Solution
  - Class Library
    - MyTraceListener.cs
    - Logger.cs
    - OtherCodeThatUsesLogger.cs
  - Winforms Project : References Class Library
    - app.config
    - WinformsCodeThatUsesLogger.cs
```

If so, I think the problem here is that your consuming code isn't using the instance of the TraceSource you created in Logger.cs.

**Logger.cs**

```
public static TraceSource trace = new TraceSource("TestApplication");
public static TraceSource opos = new TraceSource("MyTraceSource");
```

**Consuming code**

```
void foo() {
    Logger.trace.TraceInformation("hello... ");
    Logger.opos.TraceInformation("muggles.");
}
```

Comment: The problem isn't listeners in a single project, I can make multiple tracesources work from a single project. The problem lies with multiple project's trace source being used programmatically

Comment: @RobertSnyder can you explain the situation a little more? Do you have a class library that defines a `TraceSource` and another project that uses it?

Comment: See edited post. The major change is in the opening paragraph. To answer your question in one word, yes.